# Select rows with MAX(datetime) and also get min values with their dates for a column?

Tags: mysql

My table is like this (np_capacity):

```
id  tower  datetime             capacity
---|----|---------------------|----------
1  | A  | 2016-05-29 09:02:41 | 34676
2  | B  | 2016-05-29 09:02:41 | 10736
5  | C  | 2016-05-29 09:02:41 | 55664
3  | D  | 2016-05-29 09:02:41 | 32622
4  | A  | 2016-05-29 13:08:38 | 5474
6  | B  | 2016-05-29 13:08:38 | 20692
7  | C  | 2016-05-29 13:08:38 | 134802
8  | D  | 2016-05-29 13:08:38 | 4754
```

and this is my query:

```
SELECT npc.*,
                (SELECT min(c2.capacity) FROM np_capacity c2 WHERE c2.tower = npc.tower AND datetime BETWEEN (NOW() - INTERVAL 14 DAY) AND NOW()) minCapacity,

                FROM (SELECT max(datetime) maxDatetime FROM np_capacity) c1
                JOIN np_capacity npc ON (npc.datetime = c1.maxDatetime)
```

It will select all the towers with the max datetime then for those towers it will also select the min capacity value in the table for the past two weeks.
The output is something like this:

```
id  tower  datetime             capacity   MinCapacity
---|----|---------------------|----------|-------------
4  | A  | 2016-05-29 13:08:38 | 5474     | 5474
6  | B  | 2016-05-29 13:08:38 | 20692    | 10736
7  | C  | 2016-05-29 13:08:38 | 134802   | 55664
8  | D  | 2016-05-29 13:08:38 | 4754     | 4754
```

Everything good so far. The datetime is for the max(datetime) and the MinCapacity is the min value for the past two weeks and also what I want.
How can I get the specific datetime also for selected MinCapacity. (MinCapacityDate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this, demonstrated in [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/15fe99/9). If there is more than 1 row with the minimum capacity, it returns the most recent date.

```
SELECT np_capacity.id, np_capacity.tower, np_capacity.datetime
        ,np_capacity.capacity, mincap.mincapacity
         ,  MAX(tmincapdatetime.datetime) AS datetimeOfMin
FROM (SELECT MAX(`datetime`) AS maxdatetime 
      FROM np_capacity) AS tmaxdatetime
JOIN np_capacity
  ON tmaxdatetime.maxdatetime = np_capacity.`datetime`
LEFT JOIN (SELECT tower, MIN(capacity) as mincapacity
           FROM np_capacity
           WHERE `datetime` BETWEEN (NOW() - INTERVAL 14 DAY) AND NOW()
           GROUP BY tower) AS mincap
  ON mincap.tower = np_capacity.tower  
LEFT JOIN np_capacity AS tmincapdatetime
   ON tmincapdatetime.`datetime` BETWEEN (NOW() - INTERVAL 14 DAY) AND NOW()
      AND mincap.tower = tmincapdatetime.tower
      AND mincap.mincapacity = tmincapdatetime.capacity
GROUP BY np_capacity.id, np_capacity.tower, np_capacity.datetime
  ,np_capacity.capacity, mincap.mincapacity
ORDER BY tower;
```

Comment: Thank you. Looks like this is going to work. The only problem here is that sometimes the capacity = 0 and the query return that row twice for some reason but adding "AND capacity != 0" below line 9 seems to work. Can I do this?

Comment: @DrLizzard - I do not understand the situation you are talking about. Go to that SQLfiddle and adjust the data to represent the problem you are describing, then share the new SQLFiddle url. I will take a look at what you are referring to.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/24639/7 The table is populated from an external source. Sometimes the capacity column contains a zero. When this happens the array returned from your query will return duplicate rows. I want to prevent selecting rows where capacity contains zero and want to know if the sqlfiddle will return correct results.

Comment: @DrLizzard - The problem is actually if there is more than 1 record with the minimum amount, then the 2nd LEFT JOIN was duplicating records.  Update the solution (including the [SQLFiddle link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/15fe99/9)

Answer (score 0):

Could by you need a join and a where in

```
select a.*, b.min(capacity) 
from np_capacity as a
where a.tower, datetime in (      
    select tower, max(datetime) 
    from np_capacity 
    group by tower) 
inner join np_capacity as b on a.tower  = b.tower 
group by a.id, a.tower, a.datetime
```